# Calculate column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query to update column 2 of table X to equal 1/2 of column 1 where column 3 is true.

```
table 1

Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
10       5          true
10                 false
20       10         true
```

Comment: i guess you have already answered your question. just change some of the words into operator :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column2 = Column1 / 2
WHERE Column3 = 1
```

Comment: I think `Column3 = 'true'` might be more appropriate for the OP's sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If so, it's poor schema. Sql Server doesn't have a "boolean" data type that uses true/false. It only has a "bit" type that uses 1/0. If he really has "true"/"false" in his db, he's doing it wrong.